# Get rid of line above UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, border, line, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` (which happens to have a `UISearchBar`) and can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the white/gray border above it.  I need to have seamless black between the `UISearchBar` and the black above it.

I have tried hiding the `UISearchBar` to see if that had anything to do with it, but the line still appeared.

Any ideas?

[image: Line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had to do with the pullToRefresh view I was using (using SensibleTableView) - it had some code in drawRect to draw the line.

Answer (score 9):

In my case it helped to set:

```
    searchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: actually this is what solved for me. The searchbar comes with a line on top for no reason!

Comment: it does not to work with uitableviewcontroller. I had to use uiviewcontroller instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to customise the UISearchBar background to match according to your requirements.,[take a look at this tutorial.](http://caydenliew.com/2012/01/customize-uisearchbar-background-image/)

Comment: I have tried using an image as the background for the UISearchBar, but that did not work - It is really the top of the UITableView that has that line.   I have also tried the following: [code] [self.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    self.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    for (id img in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([img isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            [img removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }[/code]

Answer (score 1):

You should try this, by which you can set the color of cell borders and if you want to change the color of a particular cell's border put it in condition as: if (indexPath.row == yourcell):

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Also the above method you have to put in CellForRowAtIndexPath method of table view datasource.

Please notify if it works..

Comment: That did indeed change the separator color to black, however the line at the top of the tableview is still gray.