# Search Display Controller Search Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is driving me crazy, I can not figure out what that black line is behind my search bar.

My view hierarchy is a UINavigationController -> UITableViewController with a SearchDisplayController, and I customize the appearance of the search bar with the following code:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[ApplicationStyle searchBarIconImage] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[ApplicationStyle searchBarImage]];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[ApplicationStyle searchBarFieldImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The image I am using for the background is 640px x 88px and it is not transparent by any means.  Any ideas what this could be?

[image]

Comment: Try set up background color for the tableView:  self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the search bar's [`clipsToBounds` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_20) to `YES`.

Relevant SO questions:

- [Is it possible to change the border color of a UISearchDisplayController's search bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702848/is-it-possible-to-change-the-border-color-of-a-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-searc)
- [Get rid of line above UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228010/get-rid-of-line-above-uitableview/14380893#14380893)

Comment: Thanks, apparently I did not search well enough